# '.' is not recognized

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, sublimetext3

I was following this tutorial for aws-php sdk [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDxCDdZFh9g&t=102s).
I Installed composer manually by using Composer-Setup.exe.
So when I am trying to install composer by clicking composer.json>Composer>install
this error appeared.

And if you have some proper tutorial for using php-sdk, please comment it here.
The tutorial is 2years outdated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is execute composer.

The correct way to execute composer in a windows based system is:

```
php composer.phar install
```

or

```
c:\path\to\php php composer.phar install
```

The approach of using ./ works with linux based systems after you have made the file executable. You generally do not require that in windows.

Go through the following links for details:

https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/composer-install-php-dependency-manager

https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/composer-install-php-dependency-manager